# Reviews: recommend deletion with "no comment needed"

Tags: support, review-queues

Is the *no comment needed* option acceptable if the comment for recommending deletion is already there, or should I choose the reason for recommending deletion even when there already is a similar comment?

Comment: What do you mean by *" if the comment for recommending deletion is already there"*? If there is already a comment recommending deletion for one of the other reasons (like, say, too broad)?

Comment: i.e. if someone comments *this should be a comment* - should I choose *This is commentary on another post, not an answer* option OR is the *no comment needed* acceptable in that case?

Comment: @JanTuroň I'd upvote the comment that said "this should be a comment" and not leave another one. Especially if the user should have known better.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli "Recommend Deletion" is an option for low-quality _answers_ only. "Too broad" is not really applicable to those.

Comment: @pizza thank you for the clarification.. it wasn't clear

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a comment isn't needed, **then don't add one.**

Comments might not be needed for all sorts of reasons. A few I can think of off the top of my head:

- An existing comment adequately describes the problem
- The author's account was deleted
- The post being deleted is clearly abuse/nonsense/cat-pictures and doesn't deserve a response.

Comment: [cat-pictures!](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/46835/31260)

Comment: Cat pictures are *always* appropriate.

Comment: another reason I see: revenge downvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't hurt to choose the same delete option that someone else already has.

If you see the same auto-generated comment that you think is appropriate (e.g. "This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification...") already there, feel free to upvote that comment, but whether you choose the "No comment needed" or the other option, it will only generate the comment once for each type instead of having the same comment from multiple people. (Just confirmed while reviewing low quality posts.)

[image]

As Shog9 said, the comment might not be needed at all, but if you're worried about duplicating generated comments, SO is clever enough to handle that.

Comment: Yes, the comment will only be auto-generated once. But are you sure the other instance was actually auto-generated, and not a helpful user outside the queue putting it there? It happens.

Comment: I used to type out *possible duplicate of <link>* because I thought that was the standard comment to post, not knowing that they are actually auto generated when you VTC as dupe

Comment: @Deduplicator: If a _similar_ comment exists, I guess having the "official" version there (including links to reputation help, etc.) as well, or even the same comment twice (if pasted manually) can't really hurt, but you're correct; I was referring to the case where the _exact same_ comment is already there.

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Yeah, I guess there's no way to know how those comments get there until you get access to the queues that put them there :-)